# Filter a SQL table according to a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have a table like this in MySQL :

```
Group Seqno Event
  1    1     A
  1    2     B
  1    3     C
  1    4     B
  1    5     E
  1    6     B
  1    7     D
  1    8     A
```

I want to count all the rows from last (most recent entry) for each Group with Event = B, and return all remaining rows as soon as it hit count of 2.
The output will be

```
Group Seqno Event
  1    4     B
  1    5     E
  1    6     B
  1    7     D
  1    8     A
```

Any idea how to achieve it.

Comment: You seem to want all rows from the second to last "B"in each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want all rows from the second to last "B"?

If so, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.seqno >= (select t2.seqno
                  from t t2
                  where t2.group = t.group and t2.event = 'B'
                  order by t2.seqnum desc
                  limit 1, 1
                 );
```

To handle the case where there may be no "second" sequence number, you can use `coalesce()`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.seqno >= coalesce( (select t2.seqno
                            from t t2
                            where t2.group = t.group and t2.event = 'B'
                            order by t2.seqnum desc
                            limit 1, 1
                           ), t.seqno
                         );
```

Comment: Thanks. I am counting the "B" from the last record of each group. For example  row  1    6     B is count 1 and  1    4     B is count 2. Now, return all the records below this row.

Comment: @No_body . . . I think this does what you want.

Comment: Thanks .It's working great  but if there is no "B" or the count is less than 2 say 1 , in such cases how should I proceed?   t2.event = 'B' will fail if there is not event B

Comment: @No_body . . . No rows will be returned in that case.  There is no "failure", just a `NULL` return value.

Comment: if count of B is less than 2 its not returning any rows for that ID. Is it possible to  put a condition like if count <2 then return all rows? .